# How to set properties to 2 domain objects using a single form and here 1 of the domain objects is acting as formbacking object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I have developed a JSP which is refering to the properties of 2 domain objects.
Here i am making one of the objects as domain and trying to set the properties using a Collection object to other domain object. But the the JSP is not getting loaded and giving only one exception that is:

org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'auction' of bean class [com.persistent.eap.domain.Auction]: Bean property 'auction' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Answer (score 3):

The error sounds like your bean property does not adhere to the java beans standard.

A java beans property must be specified like this:

```
private [type] [name];
public void set[Name]([type] [name]);
public [type] get[Name]();
```

if `[type]` is `boolean`, then the get method may also (and should) be called

```
public [type] is[Name]();
```

Valid examples:

```
private int foo;
public void setFoo(int foo){this.foo=foo;}
public int getFoo(){return this.foo;}


private boolean bar;
public void setBar(boolean bar){this.bar=bar;}
public boolean isBar(){return this.bar;}
```

The important things are:

1. Naming conventions

   - setter name = "set" + field name (first letter capitalized)
   - getter name = "get" + field name (first letter capitalized)
     (or, for boolean fields only): "is" + field name (first letter capitalized)
2. Correct types

   - setter must have a single parameter of the same type as the field, return type must be void (e.g. fluent setters are not allowed)
   - getter must have no parameters, return type must be field type

**Reference:**

- [JavaBean conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBean#JavaBean_conventions) (wikipedia)

Comment: I realize this is very old at this point, but thank you for your well written answer.  It helped me find an oversight that may have taken me ages.

Comment: @Wes thanks. this is actually what StackOverflow is about. Helipng one asker, but providing references for future askers as well.